Plot date and time interval and duration during night
I have a list of date+time start and stop that I would like to plot as bars. The X-axis should go from 18:00-06:00 (midnight at center) with date on the Y-axis.
With the following code, intervals which cross midnight are handled incorrectly.
### plot start stop times
reset session

$Data <<EOD
06.03.2019  09:45   11:17
07.03.2019  22:40   03:20
EOD

StartDay = "06.03.2019"
DaysAfterStartDay(day) = int((strptime("%d.%m.%Y",day)-strptime("%d.%m.%Y",StartDay))/86400)

set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M"

plot $Data u (timecolumn(2)):(y=DaysAfterStartDay(strcol(1))): \
    (timecolumn(2)):(timecolumn(3)):(y-0.2):(y+0.2):ytic(1) w boxxyerror \
    fs solid 1.0 lc rgb "blue" notitle
### end of code

tried this but do not works...please help.
set xrange ["05:00":"19:00"]
set xtics add ("13:00" "01:00")
set xtics add ("14:00" "02:00")
set xtics add ("15:00" "03:00")
set xtics add ("16:00" "04:00")
set xtics add ("18:00" "06:00")
set xtics add ("19:00" "07:00")
set xtics add ("20:00" "08:00")
set xtics add ("21:00" "09:00")
set xtics add ("22:00" "10:00")
set xtics add ("23:00" "11:00")
set xtics add ("00:00" "12:00")
set xtics add ("01:00" "13:00")
set xtics add ("02:00" "14:00")
set xtics add ("03:00" "15:00")
set xtics add ("04:00" "16:00")
set xtics add ("05:00" "17:00")
set xtics add ("06:00" "18:00")
set xtics add ("08:00" "20:00")
set xtics add ("09:00" "21:00")
set xtics add ("10:00" "22:00")
set xtics add ("11:00" "23:00")
set xtics add ("12:00" "24:00")


Welcome to StackOverflow! So, with "your" code you are referring to this post. What about events that start e.g. after midnight, how do you do you want them to be displayed? At the previous date? And do you have events which start before 18:00 or end after 06:00? If yes, how do you want to handle them?

The following solution comes to my mind.
Some comments:

gnuplot does date/time calculations with seconds passed from Jan. 1st 1970. Hence, one day has Day = 24*60*60 = 86400 seconds

in your data each line has one date and two times. Hence, the assumption is that the intervals are always <24 hours in duration. So, if the time in column 3 is smaller than the time in column 2, then the time in column 3 is on the next day, hence add one day

simply plot the time intervals 3 times, shifted in x-direction by -24, 0, and +24 hours, and shifted in y-direction by -1,0,+1 day, accordingly. You can do this with a for-loop.
If you let auto-range and auto-coloring on, this would look like this:




now you limit the x-range to the desired time window range (here: tStart 18:00, tEnd 06:00 + Day

additionally (but not strictly necessary) you can also completely suppress the boxes which are outside this window by setting, e.g. the x-coordinate of the boxxyerror 6-columns style (check help boxxyerror) to NaN, i.e.  t0>tEnd || t1<tStart ? NaN : t1

furthermore, you can link y1 and y2 axes via set link (check help link). So get different date labels on y1- and y2-axes


Script:
### plot start/stop times over midnight
reset session

$Data <<EOD
06.03.2019  17:00   21:00
07.03.2019  19:00   22:00
07.03.2019  23:00   02:00
08.03.2019  22:00   01:00
09.03.2019  09:00   12:00  # this will not appear in the graph
10.03.2019  02:00   03:00
10.03.2019  04:00   20:00  # this will show up on two lines
11.03.2019  23:00   19:00  # ditto
12.03.2019  21:00   05:00
EOD

fmtH   = "%H:%M"
fmtD   = "%d.%m.%Y"
Day    = 86400     # 1 day = 86400 secs
tStart = strptime(fmtH,"18:00")
tEnd   = strptime(fmtH,"06:00") + Day
BoxH   = 0.7    # box height

set xrange[tStart:tEnd]
set format x fmtH timedate
set yrange[:] noextend
set offset 0,0,Day/2,Day/2
set format y fmtD timedate
set grid x,y
set tics out
set arrow from first Day, graph 0 to first Day, graph 1 nohead dt 2
set style fill transparent solid 0.3
set key noautotitle
set link y2 via y+Day inverse y-Day
set format y2 fmtD timedate
set y2tics nomirror

plot for [i=-1:1] $Data u ( \
     t0=timecolumn(2,fmtH)+i*Day, t1=timecolumn(3,fmtH)+ i*Day, \
     t1=t1+(t1<t0 ? Day :0), t0>tEnd || t1<tStart ? t1 : t1): \
     (y0=timecolumn(1,fmtD)-i*Day):(t0):(t1): \
     (y0-Day*BoxH*0.5):(y0+Day*BoxH*0.5) w boxxy lc "blue"
### end of script

Result:

